# How to prune this type of sorted weighted trees to maximize this particular function?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, tree, mathematical-optimization, graph-algorithm

**Disclaimer #1:** I'm not a pro, so many of my nomenclatures might be not standard or useful. Please bear with me / edit me.

**Disclaimer #2:** As the tags suggest, this may start out as a theoretical question, but I think it's a programming one, though some theory would also be nice.

First, let me describe this type of sorted weighted trees, now called **SWR trees**. Let `T = (V, E, W, U, m, r)` be an SWR tree. The **only** defining properties of `T` are:

- `T` is a `m`-ary rooted tree with root `r`, and every leaf has the same height/level in `T`
- `T` has predefined and unchanged weights on edges, defined by the function `W: E -> R+` (`R+` is the set of positive real numbers)
- `T` has predefined and unchanged weights on leaves, defined by the function `U: V_L -> R+` (`V_L` is the set of leaves in `V`)
- For each non-leaf node `v` of `T`, its children are sorted in the increasing values of the edges connecting them to `v`

Now, let me describe **the function** on `T`, now called `F(T)`. `F` will produce a number on `T` as follows:

- Extend the function `U` to `U*: V -> R+` as follows: for each non-leaf node `v`, assign to `v` the largest value of the *child* edges of `v` (the edges connecting v to its children)
- For each height/level `h` of `T`, calculate `f(h)` as the minimum value of the vertices (defined by `U*`) at that height/level
- Sum all of the `f(h)` to get `F(T)`

Also, let me describe the **proper pruning** process on `T`. Consider the pruning of the edges. When an edge is pruned, its sub-tree is removed. Not only that, all of its larger edges (and their sub-trees) are also removed (keep in mind, due to the sorting, only consider the larger *sibling* edges). Hence, the remaining tree `T'` is still an SWR tree and properly inherits all properties from `T`. Obviously, `F(T')` has changed (even `U*` and `f` have changed).

Therefore, the problem arises. **Given an SWR tree `T`, how can one properly prune it to get an SWR tree `T'` with the maximum value of `F` ?**

**Disclaimer #3:** I'm aware of the fact that the problem is like fallen from the sky and rather messy. Please feel free to reformulate it as you like. Also, just to formulate the problem itself exhausts me a bit, so I have had no handle to solve this yet.

Comment: Could you be more precise about "descendant edges"? Are these the edges connecting v to its children or all edges in v's subtree, or something else?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Sorry it's indeed confusing, I mean "child edges" - the edges connecting v to its children. I fixed the question. Hope it's clearer.

Comment: I assume from the text that `V_L` is leaves, and `R` I assume is the real numbers. Is it indeed possible for the weights to be negative, or did you mean R^+?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat You are right on both. About the negativity of the weights, I assume because the processes only require sorting and comparing, so it doesn't matter. I can be wrong though.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it depends on what happens when we remove all nodes at a particular height.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat That's true. I wrongly assume it's always better to keep the height of `T`. I fixed that. Now only positive weights allowed, so the height is kept.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first simplify your problem definition slightly by removing the leaf weights. Now that none of the weights are negative, we can put a single child under each leaf and move each leaf's weight to its new child edge.

I can write down what seems like a pretty tight integer program that captures this problem. For each edge `e`, the variable `x[e]` is 1 if we keep the edge, 0 otherwise. The variable `y[e]` is 1 if `e` is the minimum value of the maximum sibling on its level, 0 otherwise.

```
maximize sum_{e} W(e) y[e]
subject to
for all e, x[e] ∈ {0, 1}
for all e, y[e] ∈ {0, 1}
for all e sibling of e' with W(e) ≤ W(e'), x[e'] − x[e] ≤ 0
for all e parent of e', x[e'] − x[e] ≤ 0
for all levels ℓ, for all e at level ℓ, for all p at level ℓ−1, y[e] + x[p] − sum_{e' child of p with W(e) ≤ W(e')} x[e] ≤ 1
for all levels ℓ, sum_{e at level ℓ} y[e] = 1
```

The first two constraint groups enforce the restrictions on pruning. The next constraint group says, essentially, an edge cannot be the minimum value of the maximum sibling on its level unless each sibling group on its level has an edge at least as valuable or is totally gone. The final constraint is only needed to break ties.

This formulation can be solved as is with an integer program solver, but I strongly suspect that there's a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: Perhaps for now this solution is satisfactory. The problem seems too hard to me, unless one can reformulate somehow to bring it closer to typical graph problems.